# Unix/GNU, cmake, and glfw setup errors: GLFW Error: X11: Failed to open X display and Error: could not initialize GLFW

Tags: unix, installation, cmake, gnu, glfw

I found a graphics course website that is open (like MIT's OpenCourseWare) and I'm try to setup my machine for it...

I am using my windows machine to remotely access a gnu server. I think that I have installed all the dependencies and have gotten assignment 1 to build, but I get the error message below when I test assignment 1. I also copied and pasted the console window after running the commands to build and test assignment 1. I don’t know how to proceed from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please give simple step-by-step instructions.

Error Messages:

[CMU462] GLFW Error: X11: Failed to open X display

[CMU462] Error: could not initialize GLFW!

```
govi@rubymta-test:~$ cd cs184
govi@rubymta-test:~/cs184$ cd asst1_rasterizester-master
govi@rubymta-test:~/cs184/asst1_rasterizester-master$ mkdir build; cd build
govi@rubymta-test:~/cs184/asst1_rasterizester-master/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.2.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Found Freetype: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so
-- Using X11 for window creation
-- Using GLX for context creation
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Looking for glXGetProcAddress
-- Looking for glXGetProcAddress - found
-- Looking for glXGetProcAddressARB
-- Looking for glXGetProcAddressARB - found
-- Looking for glXGetProcAddressEXT
-- Looking for glXGetProcAddressEXT - not found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/govi/cs184/asst1_rasterizester-master/build
govi@rubymta-test:~/cs184/asst1_rasterizester-master/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target glew
[  2%] Building C object CGL/deps/glew/CMakeFiles/glew.dir/src/glew.c.o
[  5%] Building C object CGL/deps/glew/CMakeFiles/glew.dir/src/glewinfo.c.o
[  7%] Building C object CGL/deps/glew/CMakeFiles/glew.dir/src/visualinfo.c.o
Linking C static library libglew.a
[  7%] Built target glew
Scanning dependencies of target glfw
[ 10%] Building C object CGL/deps/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/context.c.o
[ 13%] Building C object CGL/deps/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/init.c.o
[ 15%] Building C object CGL/deps/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/input.c.o
[ 18%] Building C object CGL/deps/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/monitor.c.o
[ 21%] Building C object CGL/deps/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/window.c.o
[ 23%] Building C object CGL/deps/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_init.c.o
[ 26%] Building C object CGL/deps/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_monitor.c.o
[ 28%] Building C object CGL/deps/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_window.c.o
[ 31%] Building C object CGL/deps/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/xkb_unicode.c.o
[ 34%] Building C object CGL/deps/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/linux_joystick.c.o
[ 36%] Building C object CGL/deps/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/posix_time.c.o
[ 39%] Building C object CGL/deps/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/posix_tls.c.o
[ 42%] Building C object CGL/deps/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/glx_context.c.o
Linking C static library libglfw3.a
[ 42%] Built target glfw
Scanning dependencies of target CGL
[ 44%] Building CXX object CGL/src/CMakeFiles/CGL.dir/vector2D.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object CGL/src/CMakeFiles/CGL.dir/vector3D.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CGL/src/CMakeFiles/CGL.dir/vector4D.cpp.o
[ 52%] Building CXX object CGL/src/CMakeFiles/CGL.dir/matrix3x3.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object CGL/src/CMakeFiles/CGL.dir/matrix4x4.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object CGL/src/CMakeFiles/CGL.dir/quaternion.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object CGL/src/CMakeFiles/CGL.dir/complex.cpp.o
[ 63%] Building CXX object CGL/src/CMakeFiles/CGL.dir/color.cpp.o
[ 65%] Building CXX object CGL/src/CMakeFiles/CGL.dir/spectrum.cpp.o
[ 68%] Building CXX object CGL/src/CMakeFiles/CGL.dir/osdtext.cpp.o
[ 71%] Building C object CGL/src/CMakeFiles/CGL.dir/osdfont.c.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object CGL/src/CMakeFiles/CGL.dir/viewer.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object CGL/src/CMakeFiles/CGL.dir/base64.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object CGL/src/CMakeFiles/CGL.dir/lodepng.cpp.o
[ 81%] Building CXX object CGL/src/CMakeFiles/CGL.dir/tinyxml2.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library libCGL.a
[ 81%] Built target CGL
Scanning dependencies of target rasterizester
[ 84%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/rasterizester.dir/texture.cpp.o
[ 86%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/rasterizester.dir/triangulation.cpp.o
[ 89%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/rasterizester.dir/svgparser.cpp.o
[ 92%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/rasterizester.dir/transforms.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/rasterizester.dir/drawrend.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/rasterizester.dir/svg.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/rasterizester.dir/main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../rasterizester
[100%] Built target rasterizester
govi@rubymta-test:~/cs184/asst1_rasterizester-master/build$ ./rasterizester ../svg/basic/test1.svg
[CMU462] GLFW Error: X11: Failed to open X display
[CMU462] Error: could not initialize GLFW!
```